# How to check gcp pubsub empty/inactive subscription

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, google-cloud-platform, review

I have an application that subscribes to a topic in GCP and when there is some messages over there it downloads them and sends them to a queue on ActiveMQ.

In order to make this process fast, I am using executorService and launching multiple threads for sending messages to activeMQ. Since this the subscription is supposed to be an ongoing task I am putting the code in a while(true) loop, and hence I can't shutdown the executorService in a normal fashion, as I will be creating and shutting down the executor service in every loop.

I am searching for an elegant way to shutdown the executorService when the subscription is empty (no data in the topic) for like 2 or 3 minutes or some inactivity window. and then of course it starts again when there is some new data.

The following is my idea which I don't like, which is just a counter that I am incrementing when the subscription retrieves no data.

I am looking for a more elegant way of doing that.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class PubSubSubscriberService {

private static final int EMPTY_SUBSCRIPTION_COUNTER = 4;
private static final Logger businessLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("BusinessLogger");
private Queue<PubsubMessage> messages = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();



public void pullMessagesAndSendToBroker(CompositeConfigurationElement cce) {

    var patchSize = cce.getSubscriber().getPatchSize();
    var nThreads = cce.getSubscriber().getSendingParallelThreads();
    var scheduledTasks = 0;
    var subscribeCounter = 0;
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = null;


    while (true) {
       try {
           if (subscribeCounter < EMPTY_SUBSCRIPTION_COUNTER) {
                log.info("Creating Executor Service for uploading to broker with a thread pool of Size: " + nThreads);
            threadPoolExecutor = getThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads);
        }

        var subscriber = this.getSubscriber(cce);
        this.startSubscriber(subscriber, cce);
        this.checkActivity(threadPoolExecutor, subscribeCounter++);


        // send patches of {{ messagesPerIteration }}
        while (this.messages.size() > patchSize) {
            if (poolIsReady(threadPoolExecutor, nThreads)) {
                UploadTask task = new UploadTask(this.messages, cce, cf, patchSize);
                threadPoolExecutor.submit(task);
                scheduledTasks ++;
            }
            subscribeCounter = 0;
        }

        // send the rest
        if (this.messages.size() > 0) {
            UploadTask task = new UploadTask(this.messages, cce, cf, patchSize);
            threadPoolExecutor.submit(task);
            scheduledTasks ++;
            subscribeCounter = 0;
        }

        if (scheduledTasks > 0) {
            businessLogger.info("Scheduled " + scheduledTasks + " upload tasks of size upto: " + patchSize + ", preparing to start subscribing for 30 more sec") ;
            scheduledTasks = 0;
        }
    } catch ( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        businessLogger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to stop your pool? What's your issue?

Comment: to free resources on the pods. when I don't do these the JVM never releases the the thread pool resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pool take few space and memory and consume almost no CPU when it's not used. Set a max limit to your Pool capacity and use it with trying to downscale it. If you have too much messages to process, the task are queued waiting a free executor pool to complete the task.

If you have scalability up and down concerne, you design could be reviewed. Instead of executorPool internal to the pod, you could trigger an event in your cluster and process them in parallel, on other pods. These pods will be able to scale up and down according to the traffic (have a look to [Knative](https://knative.dev/))